# Magical Record - MR_createEntity returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, magicalrecord

I can't find out what's wrong with my code. I'm trying to use MagicalRecord with Swift. When i'm doing simple createEntity it gives me nil:

```
let a = Subject.MR_createEntity() <--- This line is working perfectly
let b = Points.MR_createEntity()  <--- This line returns nil
let c = Class.MR_createEntity()   <--- This line returns nil
```

This is my class implementations:

Subject:

```
@objc(Subject)
class Subject: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var classes: NSSet?
}
```

Class:

```
@objc(Class)
class Class: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var teacherName: String?
    @NSManaged var subject: Subject?
    @NSManaged var points: NSSet?
}
```

Points:

```
@objc(Points)
class Points: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var date: NSDate?
    @NSManaged var points: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var maxPoints: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var classType: Class?
}
```

And screen from .xcdatamodel:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. In your .xcdatamodel **Editor-->Add Model Version...-->Finish**
2. Now **Product-->Clean**

Everything is working.

Answer (score 1):

When initializing MagicalRecord, you can enable ***core data*** log, then you will know what happens when failing to create entity.

```
MagicalRecord.setLoggingLevel(MagicalRecordLoggingLevel.Warn)
```